# Displaying PowerPoint on iPad with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, powerpoint

I'm looking for the best way to display MS PowerPoint presentations (ppt/pptx) in my iPad application (Objective-C).

I read a lot about UIWebView (which I'm using to display pdf), but it doesn't seem to work well with ppt/pptx.

Is there other ways to properly process those types of files (with animations, slide control)?

Comment: Look at those answers of similar questions in Stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18609684/1665702
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15428110/1665702