# Displaying PowerPoint Slides in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, powerpoint

I would like to ask if it is possible to display PowerPoint through either TableViewController or UIButton instead of using a UIWebView?

The PowerPoint Slides are being stored in a folder in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're envisaging with a UIButton, that makes very little sense to me, but you can of course put a UIWebView in a table cell. I assume that's not what you want?

You're probably best off pre-processing the PowerPoint files on a back-end server to convert them to PDFs. (or as part of your build process, if they're static) You have a lot more options for displaying those on iOS.

Comment: If i can convert it to PDF, will i be able to display the PDF files from a folder in Xcode locally instead of using a UIWebView to get the PDF files from online?

Comment: 2 things: 1- UIWebView can display local files stored in your app bundle too, no need to fetch them over a network. To do so pass the webview a local (file://) url, such as: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"mypresentation" withExtension:@"ppt]`. 2- PDF files are very well supported on iOS, you have quite a lot of control over rendering them. For an introduction, see http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/ (but there's loads of documentation on this out there)

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways of what you can do. You could of course use the

[Quick Look Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html) to display the ppt even without converting it to pdf.
Also the UIWebView should be capable of presenting your ppt without the need to convert it.

The problem with these solutions is that you will **lose all animations** in your presentation. The only solution I know that wont destroy your animations is to either export your presentation directly as HMTL file or to use programs such as [PPTToHTML5Converter](http://www.digitalofficepro.com/powerpoint/powerpoint-to-html5-converter.html) to convert your ppt to an HTML5 file and show that in your UIWebView.

I hope I could help.