# iOS framework/library for presenting Powerpoint slides?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I need a framework/library which can help me in to present the PPT slides with good animations?

Any ideas where i can find one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Quick Look Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html)** should be what you need - It is available in iOS 4.0 and later.

> "Use the Quick Look framework to provide previews of items that are in
>   formats you don’t handle—such as iWork or Microsoft Office."

A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:

- iWork documents
- Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
- Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
- PDF files
- Images
- Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the
  public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)
- Comma-separated value (csv) files

[Here](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/17/load-a-pdf-file-in-the-iphone-app-smoothly/) is an example tutorial of Quick Look being used to display a PDF documents, not too dissimilar to what you'll need to do with your `.ppt` document.

Comment: Thanks, will try and integrate it :)

Comment: Also look at [UIDocumentationInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html), which may be easier than using Quick Look, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the document viewer. This works fine for all type of files.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html