# iOS view PPT with animation

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiwebview, powerpoint

Is there a way to view PPT files without losing the animations? I know `UIWebView` shows PPT but it strips off the animation, is there any other framework?

Comment: Check out my answer here, hopefully it's what you want -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428085/ios-framework-library-for-presenting-powerpoint-slides/15428110#15428110